# Sort rows by reference column with id with elasicsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

For example I have a index `purcahses` with column `createdBy` which has `id` of user from another index.
In result I want to get purchases sorted by user `name`.
Beside storing user name in that table what other ways of sorting could be?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this applicable in `Elasticsearch`, you can make queries on multiple `indices`, but I don't think you can use the query result in another query dynamically, which's necessary to get *users names* from `users` index based on *user id* from `purcahses` to apply the sorting criteria.

I think you can do that from your application in 2 separated queries.